# Editing a page from wordpress does not show in git?

Tags: wordpress, git, custom-wordpress-pages

So I downloaded wordpress. I edited the home page via the pages section and clicked update. Doing a `git status` does not show any changes. Where is the edited section stored? I am not using the internet and I have git initialized in the wordpress folder root.

Comment: It’s stored in the database, not any of the files. It’s not tracked by Git in any way.

Answer (score 1):

As you see, git status does not show any changes because it displays paths that have differences between the index file and the current commit. i.e it shows only the files where code is changed. 
In wordpress, page data/content saves in database rather than a file.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress working with database. Your changes from wp-admin do not update any file.
So, your files have not changed and git is not interested in this.
If you want get more info for WP database system can [click here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description).